Type Error in Next.js Route: "Type '{ params: { id: string; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps'" (NextJS 15)
I'm encountering an issue when trying to use asynchronous parameters in a Next.js 15 app. I want to extract the slug parameter from params, which is returned as a Promise.
Here's my current setup in page.tsx:
type tParams = Promise<{ slug: string[] }>;

export default async function Challenge({ params }: { params: tParams }) {
  const { slug } = await params;
  const productID = slug[1];

  // other code here
}

When I run npm run build, I get this error:

Type error: Type '{ params: { id: string; }; }' does not satisfy the
constraint 'PageProps'. Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
Type '{ id: string; }' is missing the following properties from type
'Promise': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]

It seems like the type for params is causing issues, possibly because Next.js expects a different structure for params.
What I’ve Tried

I initially defined params as { slug: string[] }, but I changed it to Promise<{ slug: string[] }> to try to handle the async behavior.
I also tried different configurations for the params type without success.

Question
How can I correctly type the params object for asynchronous access in Next.js 15, or is there a different recommended approach for this?

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/version-15#asynchronous-layout

From the example in the migration guide they show that you can't use the destructured members of an asynchronous page props...
Maybe try this change -
type tParams = Promise<{ slug: string[] }>;

export default async function Challenge(props: { params: tParams }) {
  const { slug } = await props.params;
  const productID = slug[1];

  // other code here
}


I fixed the issue by doing this
without async await

import { use } from "react";
    
export default function CategoryDetail({params}: {params: Promise<{ id: string }>}) {
const { id } = use(params);
...

with async await
    
export default async function CategoryDetail({params}: {params: Promise<{ id: string }>}) {
const { id } = await params;
...


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

install this
npx @next/codemod@latest next-async-request-api .
type tParams = Promise<{ slug: string[] }>;

export default async function Challenge({ params }: { params: tParams }) {
  const { slug } = await params;
  const productID = slug[1];
}

just install it  you did correct

Could you add a document linked to it

Nextjs 15 dynamic rendering works with this pattern
export default async function PostPage(params: { 
 params: Promise<{ slug: string }>;) {
  const slug = await(params).slug;
  return <Block slug={slug}/>
}


here is a link to the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#example

type tParams = { slug: string[] };

export default async function Challenge({ params }: { params: tParams }) {
  // No need to await `params` here since it's not a Promise anymore
  const { slug } = params;
  const productID = slug[1];

  // other code here
}


based on nextjs15 docs, you can do this:
export default async function Page({
  params,
}: {
  params: Promise<{ slug: string }>
}) {
  const slug = (await params).slug
  return <div>My Post: {slug}</div>
}


Do not destructure slug again, I used this format and it worked fine,
const Page = async ({ params }: { params: Promise<{ id: string }>
}) => {
const id = (await params).id;

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

For even the projects that run v14 have to be updated using some scenarios mentioned in here. In my case the issue was with async server components receiving params as props. Here is a general solution mentioned in the source documentation:
type Params = Promise<{ slug: string }>
type SearchParams = Promise<{ [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }>
 
export async function generateMetadata(props: {
  params: Params
  searchParams: SearchParams
}) {
  const params = await props.params
  const searchParams = await props.searchParams
  const slug = params.slug
  const query = searchParams.query
}
 
export default async function Page(props: {
  params: Params
  searchParams: SearchParams
}) {
  const params = await props.params
  const searchParams = await props.searchParams
  const slug = params.slug
  const query = searchParams.query
}


There is documentation about Asynchronous Page in the Next.js:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/version-15#asynchronous-page
Try that approach, which is in the Next.js documentation:
export default async function Challenge(
 props: {
  params: Promise<{ slug: string }>;
 }
) {
 const params = await props.params;
 const productID = params.slug[1];
 // const productID = params.slug;
 // other code here
}


You can write it like this.(App Router)
import { EventDetail } from "@/components/organisms/event-detail";

export default async function EventPage({ params }: { params: Promise<{ 
eventId: string }> }) {

    const { eventId } = await params;

    return (
        <main className="">
           <EventDetail eventId={eventId} />
        </main>
    );
}


Here is how fix this issue:
import Link from "next/link";
import photos, { Photo } from "@/lib/";
import PhotoCard from "@/components/photo-card";
export const generateStaticParams = () => {
  return photos.map(({ id }) => ({
    id: String(id),
  }));
};
export type paramsType = Promise<{ id: string }>;

export default async function PhotoPage(props: { params: paramsType }) {
  const { id } = await props.params;
  const photo: Photo | undefined = photos.find((p) => p.id === id);

  if (!photo) {
    return <div>Photo not found</div>;
  }

  return (
    <section className="py-24">
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          <Link
            href="/photos"
            className="font-semibold italic text-sky-600 underline"
          >
            Back to photos
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-10 w-1/3">
          <PhotoCard photo={photo} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

install npx @next/codemod@canary next-async-request-api .
and then  const BlogPage = async ({ params }: { params: Promise<{ id: string }> }) => { const { id } = await params; const blog = blogs.find((blog) => blog.id === id); return JSX  };
